# Cycling through count in React component

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, url, react-component

I'm attempting to display an image with each pokemon name in react. I'm new to react, and can't find a way to cycle through the list count to display the correct name with the correct pokemon. If I take out "{test}" and insert a static number in the src url the code works fine displaying one image, but I can't find a way to update the url with +1 to display the correct image with each pokemon name.

My component code is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './card.styles.css';

export const Card = props => (
    <div className = 'card-container'>
        <img alt="monster" 
        {test = props.monster.url[36]}
        src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/${test}.png`}
        width='180'
        />
        <h2> {props.monster.name} </h2>
        <p>{props.monster.email}</p>
    </div>
);
```

and my app.js code is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {CardList} from './components/card-list/card-list.component.jsx';
import { SearchBox } from './components/search-box/search-box.component.jsx';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      monsters: [],
      searchField: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    fetch('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(pokemon => this.setState({ monsters: pokemon.results}));

  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({searchField: e.target.value})
}

  render() {
    const { monsters, searchField} = this.state;
    const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter(monster => 
      monster.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
      );
    return (
      <div className='App'>
      <h1>Pokemon Rollodex</h1>
      <SearchBox
        placeholder='search monsters'
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      <CardList monsters={filteredMonsters}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Card-list code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from '../card/card.component';
import './card-list.styles.css';

export const CardList = props => (
    <div className='card-list'>
    {props.monsters.map(monster => (
        <Card key ={monster.name} monster={monster} />
      ))}
    </div>
);
```

API response (pokemon name and url):

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "bulbasaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"}
1: {name: "ivysaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"}
2: {name: "venusaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"}
3: {name: "charmander", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"}
4: {name: "charmeleon", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"}
5: {name: "charizard", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"}
6: {name: "squirtle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"}
7: {name: "wartortle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"}
8: {name: "blastoise", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"}
9: {name: "caterpie", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/"}
10: {name: "metapod", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"}
11: {name: "butterfree", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/"}
12: {name: "weedle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/13/"}
13: {name: "kakuna", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/14/"}
14: {name: "beedrill", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15/"}
15: {name: "pidgey", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/16/"}
16: {name: "pidgeotto", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/17/"}
17: {name: "pidgeot", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/18/"}
18: {name: "rattata", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/19/"}
19: {name: "raticate", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/"}
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: can you provide your card list code? also your api response

Comment: @JatinParmar added the card list code, and the api response.

Comment: please check my answer ,hope it will helo you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i can see ,your response is collection of object containing pokemon name and api url
to get pokemon details.
now if you take a look on format of url,the url contains id of pokemon as last uri param
you just need to get that id from url and generate image url from it.
you can get pokemon id from url as :

```
 url.split("pokemon/")[1].replace('/','')
```

now your card component should be like this:

```
 export const Card = props => {
  let id=props.monster.url.split("pokemon/")[1].replace('/','')
 return (  
   <div className = 'card-container'>
    <img alt="monster" 
    src={'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/'+id+'.png'}
    width='180'
    />
    <h2> {props.monster.name} </h2>
    <p>{props.monster.email}</p>
</div>
 )}
```

consider the following snippet

```js
//cart component
const Card = props => {
  let id=props.monster.url.split("pokemon/")[1].replace('/','')
 return (  
   <div className = 'card-container'>
    <img alt="monster" 
    src={'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/'+id+'.png'}
    width='180'
    />
    <h2> {props.monster.name} </h2>
    <p>{props.monster.email}</p>
</div>
 )}
//card list component
 const CardList = props => (
    <div className='card-list'>
    {props.monsters.map(monster => (
        <Card key ={monster.name} monster={monster} />
      ))}
    </div>
);

class App extends React.Component{

render(){
let data=[ {name: "bulbasaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"},
 {name: "ivysaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"},
 {name: "venusaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"},
 {name: "charmander", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"},
 {name: "charmeleon", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"},
 {name: "charizard", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"},
 {name: "squirtle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"},
 {name: "wartortle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"},
 {name: "blastoise", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"},
 {name: "caterpie", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/"},
 {name: "metapod", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"},
 {name: "butterfree", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/"},
 {name: "weedle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/13/"},
{name: "kakuna", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/14/"},
{name: "beedrill", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15/"},
{name: "pidgey", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/16/"},
{name: "pidgeotto", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/17/"},
{name: "pidgeot", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/18/"},
{name: "rattata", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/19/"},
{name: "raticate", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/"}];

  //here just for demo i am using static data
 return  <CardList monsters={data}/>
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **delete** `{test=props.monster.url[36]}` and directly use it in the src tag as;

```js
import React from 'react';
import './card.styles.css';

export const Card = props => (
    <div className = 'card-container'>
        <img alt="monster" 
        src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/${props.monster.url[36]}.png`}
        width='180'
        />
        <h2> {props.monster.name} </h2>
        <p>{props.monster.email}</p>
    </div>
);
```

You cannot create a state by doing

```js
export const Card = props => (
  {test = props.monster.url[36]}
...
```